# How can I tell if a fortran array pointer has been allocated directly, or is associated with another object?

Tags: arrays, pointers, memory-leaks, fortran, fortran90

I am working with a fortran code which contains some array pointers; depending on the user input, they might either be set to point to another array with the assignment statement `=>`, or they might be directly allocated with the `allocate` statement.

This creates a problem for freeing memory at the end of the code, because in the first case I just want to `nullify` the pointer, while in the second case I need to `deallocate` it to prevent a memory leak. The problem is that in both cases `associated` returns *true*, so I don't know how to tell which case I'm in without keeping track of it manually. Since there are many such array pointers I would prefer to avoid having to do so.

Is there a simple way to distinguish between the two cases?

Thank you!

Comment: By "at the end of the code", how close to the end do you mean?  Throughout execution I may care about memory leaks, etc., but at the end of my program it's no longer my responsibility to ensure everything is tidied up.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean... surely I should aim for all memory that was allocated to be deallocated before the program terminates?

Comment: I meant, consider the (horrible) program: `allocatable i; allocate(i); end`.  I don't feel the slightest bit of guilt in not having a `deallocate` in there.  There are times when I want to be responsible for deallocation, but not here.  Is the premise of your question that there should be a `deallocate` statement?  My first comment was just to establish that.

Comment: Ah sorry, yes I am feeling guilty! There should be a `deallocate` for every `allocate`. If I do: `integer, pointer :: i(:); allocate i(5); nullify(i); end` then I will end up with some space which is not deallocated and also inaccessible to the code.

Comment: Just to be clear, lest anyone else stumble across this question and get as confused as I did -- there's absolutely no need to explicitly free memory, either using `deallocate` or `nullify` at the end of a program.  Unless your o/s is broken it is going to reap all the memory allocated to the program when the program ends.  It would be a different matter if OP's concern was to reap memory at another point during execution.  Worth bearing in mind too that the latest editions of the Fortran standard guarantee deallocation when an allocated object goes out of scope.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This sounds like a horrible mess. I assume that you have something like this:

```
program really_bad
    implicit none
    integer, dimension(:), pointer :: a
    integer, dimension(:), allocatable, target :: b
    logical :: point_to_b

    allocate(b(10))
    write(*, *) "Should I point to B?"
    read(*, *) point_to_b

    if (point_to_b) then
        a => b
    else
        allocate(a(10))
    end if

    ! Destroy A

end program really_bad
```

And your issue is the destroying part. If `a` is pointing to `b`, then you want to `NULLIFY` it, because you need to keep `b`. But if `a` is not pointing to `b`, and you only `NULLIFY` it, you get a memory leak.

As @ian-bush points out, you can check whether something is associated with something else, but that would mean that you have to compare the pointer with all possible targets, and you claim that you have many of those.

One thing you could try, but this is probably even worse an idea, is to try to deallocate, and use its `STAT=` dummy argument to check whether the deallocation actually worked. Please note that this is a terrible hack, and I only got it to work on Intel, not on GFortran, but here goes nothing:

```
program don
    implicit none
    integer, dimension(:), pointer :: a
    integer, dimension(:), target, allocatable :: b
    logical :: point_to_b
    integer :: stat

    allocate(b(10))
    b = (/ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 /)
    write(*, *) "Should I point to B?"
    read(*, *) point_to_b
    if ( point_to_b ) then
        a => b
    else
        allocate(a(10))
    end if
    deallocate(a, stat=stat)
    if ( stat /= 0 ) nullify(a)
end program don
```

A far better method would probably be to replace your array pointers with types that have both the pointer and a flag how it was associated.

```
program don
    implicit none
    type :: my_array_pointer_type
        integer, dimension(:), pointer :: array
        logical :: master
    end type my_array_pointer_type
    type(my_array_pointer_type) :: a
    integer, dimension(:), target, allocatable :: b
    logical :: point_to_b
    integer :: stat

    allocate(b(10))

    b = (/ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 /)
    write(*, *) "Should I point to B?"
    read(*, *) point_to_b
    if ( point_to_b ) then
        a%master = .false.
        a%array => b
    else
        a%master = .true.
        allocate(a%array(10))
    end if

    if (a%master) then
        deallocate(a%array)
    else
        nullify(a%array)
    end if
end program don
```

**Neither of these suggestions will help you if you might then point another pointer at `a` and then try to destroy it**. In that case I really suggest to rethink your whole project design.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. You have completely understood the situation.

I have also come to the conclusion that your last method with the additional flag is the only way forward (nothing else will point to the pointers, so no problems there). I was hoping to be able to avoid that, but it seems like there really is no other way.

Answer (score 4):

How complicated is your data structure? That is, how many pointers are simultaneously associated to a single target at a given time? The Fortran standard is completely silent when it comes to reference counting a target instantiated through the `allocate` statement, i.e., it doesn't specify a mechanism to ensure that the target memory is released when all of it's pointees are disassociated. Built-in garbage collection is precisely why the `allocatable` attribute is prefered over the `pointer` attribute 99.9% of the time. In the rare event that you absolutely must use a pointer and its target is allocated in some other subprogram, then passed up the call chain to a different procedure, tracking pointer ownership becomes a nightmare.

If you have access to a modern Fortran compiler (2008+), the following module might be helpful; FYI, variables declared in a module automatically inherit the `save` attribute. The target `foo` is a private module variable and `ref_counter` keeps track of the number of pointers associated with `foo`. By overloading the `deallocate` statement we can safely nullify, or nullify + deallocate. with `call deallocate(some_ptr, dealloc_stat)`

```
module foo_target

  ! Explicit typing only
  implicit none

  private
  public :: deallocate, nullify, point_at_foo

  ! Neither foo nor ref_counter are public
  real, pointer      :: foo(:) => null()
  integer, protected :: ref_counter = 0

  interface deallocate
     module procedure deallocate_ptr
  end interface deallocate

  interface nullify
     module procedure nullify_ptr
  end interface nullify

contains

  subroutine deallocate_ptr(ptr_to_foo, return_stat)
    ! Dummy arguments
    real, pointer, intent (in out) :: ptr_to_foo(:)
    integer,       intent (out)    :: return_stat
    ! Local variables
    enum, bind(C)
       enumerator :: DEALLOC_ERROR=1, NO_ASSOC, BAD_ASSOC
    end enum
    integer :: alloc_stat

    ! Initialize
    return_stat = 0

    block_construct: block

      ! Check association
      if (ref_counter == 0 .or. .not. associated(foo)) then
          return_stat  = NO_ASSOC
          exit block_construct
      else if (.not. associated(ptr_to_foo, foo)) then
          return_stat = BAD_ASSOC
          exit block_construct
      end if

      if (ref_counter > 1 ) then
          ! Further associations still persist, only nullify
          call nullify(ptr_to_foo)
      else if (ref_counter == 1) then
          ! No remaining associations, nullify and deallocate
          call nullify(ptr_to_foo)
          deallocate(foo, stat=alloc_stat)
          ! Check deallocation status
          if (alloc_stat /= 0) return_stat = DEALLOC_ERROR
      end if

    end block block_construct

  end subroutine deallocate_ptr


  subroutine nullify_ptr(ptr_to_foo)
      ! Dummy arguments
      real, pointer, intent (in out) :: ptr_to_foo(:)

      ! Terminate association
      nullify(ptr_to_foo)

      ! Decrement
      ref_counter = ref_counter - 1

    end subroutine nullify_ptr


    function point_at_foo() result (return_value)
      ! Dummy arguments
      real, pointer :: return_value(:)

      ! Establish association
      return_value => foo

      ! Increment
      ref_counter = ref_counter + 1

    end function point_at_foo

end module foo_target
```

Comment: I use some similar construct, but in my opinion the full power of reference counting one gets only when you create a whole new reference derived type and overload the assignments and implement finalizations (in a similar way as your nullify_ptr and point_at_foo.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it will be be useful to someone. I pushed to GitHub my simple implementation of reference counting which enables you to track references to variables. When number of references is 0 the object is automatically deallocated. Link https://github.com/LadaF/Fortran-RefCount

It is based on ideas from paper [Car - A reference counting implementation in Fortran 95/2003](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/1753166.1753168) and book [Scientific Software Design: The Object-Oriented Way](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521888131).

The reference object itself stores a pointer to another object `refptr` which stores the pointer to the data itself and the number of references pointing to it. Assignments are overloaded so that the reference count is updated. Finalization of reference objects subtracts from the reference counts as required.

```
  type refptr
    integer :: ref_count = 0
    class(*), allocatable :: data
  contains
    final :: refptr_finalize
  end type

  type :: ref
    type(refptr),pointer :: ptr => null()
    integer :: weak = 0 !1.. this is a weak reference, -1.. make weak references to this
  contains
    procedure :: assign_star
    generic :: assignment(=) => assign_star
    ...
    procedure :: pointer => ref_pointer
    final :: ref_finalize
  end type

  interface ref
    module procedure ref_init
    module procedure ref_init_1
  end interface
```

Usage is then very simple:

```
type(ref) :: a, b

a = 42
print *, "a:", a%value(0)

!this does not copy the value, it points the reference
b = a
print *, "b:", b%value(0)

!sets a to point to something new, b still points to 42
a = 2.3
```

Disclaimer: The automatic finalization has just been implemented and not tested too much. I have so far used it with manual calls to finalize in gfortran-4.8. This has been tested quite extensively.